# Can't install the latest version of python package

Tags: pip, conda, pyarrow, conda-forge

I am trying to install pyarrow 0.16 that seems to be available:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyarrow

when I execute one of the below, 0.15.1 gets installed

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pyarrow
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken pyarrow
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyarrow
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pyarrow
```

pip install installs 0.15.1 as well

I tried to use conda env:

```
conda create -n work1 pyarrow=0.16.0
```

and get this:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pyarrow=0.16.0

Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: That's odd. Can you add the output of `conda config --show subdirs`?

Comment: Can you provide the python version of your conda environment? Maybe the latest pyarrow version is not released for your python version.

Comment: @cel ,
subdirs:
  - win-64
  - noarch

Comment: @pablosjv I use base conda environment and installed fresh anaconda 3 weeks ago. Python 3.7.6

Comment: First add conda-forge as channel and set the channel priority (see https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge), and then try to re-create the env `conda create -n work1 pyarrow=0.16.0`

Comment: @joris thanks a lot, it worked. If you post it as answer, I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version is available from the conda-forge channel. If you want to install it from there, it is recommended to create a new conda environment. First add conda-forge as channel and set the channel priority (see [instructions](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge)):

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

and then try to re-create the environment:

```
conda create -n work1 pyarrow=0.16.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Check *pyarrow* dependencies from https://pypi.org/pypi/pyarrow/json
In `['info']['requires_dist']` you find:

```
['numpy (>=1.14)',  
 'six (>=1.0.0)',  
 'futures; python_version < "3.2"',  
 'enum34 (>=1.1.6); python_version < "3.4"']
```

You can then also download pyarrow-0.16.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (or whatever version you need) directly from https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/#files and pip install it.

Comment: I think it's generally not good advice to recommend pip installations when the question explicitly mentions a conda problem. IMO that's more patching the symptoms than solving the underlying issue.

Comment: The questioner explicitly mentioned a pip problem too(!), and in general there is nothing wrong with a pip installation into a **separate** 'work1' conda environment, see the official documentation [Installing non conda packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages). Especially I see no problem in checking the dependencies by looking into pypi, as this could give a hint about why the conda installation failed in the first place.

Comment: However, in the end it's a trade-off between being able to use the features from the latest *pyarrow* version vs. "potentially" suffering from stability or compatibility issues. In the worst case one can always delete the 'work1' environment - and this is what environments are made for.

Comment: I was looking for a help with conda, and pip tried just to see what happens.
I managed to install pyarrow from whl file, however then deleted it and installed 0.15.1 from conda. @Peter I have a fresh conda installation so the dependencies you mentioned were already installled.

Comment: So when you've been actually using my answer: Does this justify a downvote then? After all I spent my time trying to help you ...

Comment: Thank for your answer. I did tried it, however rolled back as I preferred stability over new features. It was not what I was looking for, but  good to know as a work around option. It was not me who downvoted though

Comment: But stability was not what you've been asking for!